# Overlay a static image on a MapView

Tags: android, image, overlay, android-mapview, transparent

I'm still a newbie to Android but have searched high and low for an answer to my problem without success.

I have a map view that the user can fully manipulate (scroll, enlarge etc.) but I need to let the user know where the midpoint of the map is.  I want to use a small "crosshair" image for this and display it at the centre of the map AT ALL TIMES and AT ALL LEVELS OF MAGNIFICATION.  In fact, I just want the image to remain on view at all times.  Can I find a way to do this? Can I hell!

I'm sure there is a very simply solution to this from one or two of you gurus out there.  Please help.

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout file that contains the MapView, make sure that the Layout container is of type RelativeLayout. Then simply add the ImageView as a child of the RelativeLayout, with an attribute of layout_gravity="center"

Basically, research RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks icecreamman, that sorted it out.  Inevitably it has raised other (unforeseen) problems but that's life!!

Comment: Awesome, can you mark this as the answer (with the green checkmark). Thanks!

Comment: @icecreamman , need your guidance, if u can help,
I want the image of map with pin dropped to lat/long I will provide.

Comment: Any change that the xml layout could be posted here by the op. Many thanks, Andy